# Wildcard vhost with modperl

Tags: apache2, vhosts, mod-perl

I have a server on which I want to run multiple wildcard vhosts, with their own modperl environment.

Each vhost needs to run it's own startup script to define custom include paths.

In a normal vhost configuration, I can do the following...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName web1.myserver.com

    Define ApplicationRoot /websites/web1

    DocumentRoot ${ApplicationRoot}

    PerlSetEnv PERL_DOC_ROOT ${ApplicationRoot}
    PerlOptions +Parent
    PerlPostConfigRequire /websites/lib/startup.pl
...
```

My startup.pl script can then use the PERL_DOC_ROOT environment variable to dynamically configure custom lib paths.

This works fine with multiple vhosts sections. They each have their own @INC defined, and everything resolves correctly.

Is there some way I can translate this to a wildcard vhost configuration. I'd like users to be able to access *.myserver.com, and it will use the hostname to figure out which documentroot to use, and will run the startup.pl to define lib paths based on this folder.

I know I can use something like this...

```
VirtualDocumentRoot /websites/%1/
```

to dynamically set the document root, but if I try to use %1 in any other declarations it is not understood. Also the startup.pl would need to run when the site is first requested, rather than when the config file is first loaded.

Is this possible at all? Or would I need to somehow dynamically rewrite the config files each time a new virtual directory is added.

Answer (score 0):

I realised I'm overcomplicating it. I don't need to use wildcard vhosts. Since I'll be using Jenkins to create the vhosts directories, I can also get it to dynamically create config files to match.